# Vieta's Formula Polynomial

Tags: polynomials

The three roots of the cubic $ 30 x^3 - 50x^2 + 22x - 1$ are distinct real numbers strictly between $ 0$ and $ 1$. If the roots are $p$, $q$, and $r$, what is the sum
$ \frac{1}{1-p} + \frac{1}{1-q} +\frac{1}{1-r} ?$

Expanding $(x-p)(x-q)(x-r)=x^{3}-(r+p+q)x^{2}+(qr+pr+pq)-pqr.$

Then, $r+q+p=50,$ and $rqp=1.$

I'm now stumped.

Comment: Check: $r+p+q=50/30$, $rqp=1/30$ and so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Simply combining the three fractions:
$$\begin{split}\frac1{1-p}+\frac1{1-q}+\frac1{1-r}&=\frac{(1-q)(1-r)+(1-p)(1-r)+(1-p)(1-q)}{(1-p)(1-q)(1-r)}\\&=\frac{3-2p-2q-2r+pr+qr+pq}{1-p-q-r+pq+qr+rp-pqr}\\
&=\frac{3-2(p+q+r)+(pr+qr+pq)}{1-(p+q+r)+(pq+qr+rp)-(pqr)}.\end{split}$$
Now, can you finish off by using Vieta's formulas?

Comment: I understand now. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let $y=\frac{1}{1-x}$ so $x=1-\frac{1}{y}$, now sub this into the equation
\begin{eqnarray*}
30 \left( 1-\frac{1}{y} \right)^3 - 50\left( 1-\frac{1}{y} \right)^2 + 22\left( 1-\frac{1}{y} \right) - 1=0.
\end{eqnarray*}
Simplify this & $\frac{1}{1-p} + \frac{1}{1-q} +\frac{1}{1-r}$ will be the coefficient of $y$ in this polynomial.

Comment: This is my way! Also we need to calculate the coefficients of $$y^3,y^2$$ only